# User identity across communities

Tags: discussion, login

I get regular emails listing questions tagged with keywords in which I have registered an interest, and some of them arise from communities in which I am not a member. If I attempt to answer these questions, the answer gets rejected unless I register or log in.

There seems a conflict here. If you want to treat me as a participant in these communities you should email me the questions and log me in automatically. If you don't want to treat me as a participant, you shouldn't send me the questions. You're inviting me to join in the party and then asking me who the hell I think I am, and it's a confusing way to treat people.

Answer (score 2):

When [creating a question notification filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/new) (watch it, non-idempotent GET request), you can leave the default "All Sites" selected, or instead enter site names under "Just these sites". If you choose the former, you might get notifications for sites on which you haven't registered an account.

You can not login if you have not registered, so your request can not be honored. Registering an account on an SE site is literally two clicks if you're already logged in.